# How to centrally justify in printf function in Perl

Tags: perl

I know the `printf` function by default uses right-justification. `-` will make it left justify. But is it possible to make it centrally justify the format?

Comment: You have to use `format` and `write`, or else roll your own.

Comment: @tchrist: This is an opportunity for someone to introduce a ± modifier for 5.16...

Comment: @ysth: Well, ’ceptin’ that’s not a 7-bit code point.

Comment: @tchrist: your point is? :)   it does feel wrong somehow to extend C-interface-minilanguages in perl, but %b and the v modifier have already done that here.

Answer (score 7):

The `printf` function cannot center text.

However, there is a very old, and almost forgotten mechanism that can do this. You can create [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) statements in Perl that tells [write](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write.html) statements how to print. By using format and write, you can center justify text.

This was something sort of done back in the days of Perl 3.x back in 1989, but sort of abandoned by the time Perl 4 came out. Perl 5, with its stronger variable scoping really put a crimp in the use of formats since using them would violate the way Perl 5 likes to scope variables (formats are global in nature).

You can learn more about it by looking at [`perldoc perlform`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). I haven't seen them used in years.

Comment: Yes and no.  `format` and `write` have been part of Perl since Day 1, appearing fully-formed right away in perl1 already, back in 1987. Yes, I remember, but I also keep the perl{1,2,3,4} manpages on my system (well, and full source), so it’s easy to check.  I like formats a lot, and still use them from time to time. I don’t think lexicals are that big a problem with formats. You just have to juggle things, or declare the formats in the lexicals’ scope. I usually make a function that I call, like say `swrite()`. Lately I’ve been cool things with `Unicode::Linebreak`.

Comment: Perl 1? I'm not quite that old. I first picked up Perl in the Perl 3 era with `chop` instead of `chomp`. In those days, the Perl books usually reserved a chapter or two on formats. Now, it's hidden away as if it was just some sort of crazy embarrassing faze that Perl went through in college.

Comment: Oh, that’s about to change. I’m moving the sprawling bodies of `sprintf` and `pack` that describe their formats out of the the 4th edition of *Programming Perl’s* chapter 29  on “Functions” and into chapter 7 on “Formats”. I’ll also add something on the fine `Unicode::LineBreak` module. These really are all linked up. Whether I’ll even mention `Perl6::Form` is undecided. I’m trying to keep the non-CORE mentions and the Perl6 mentions to a minimum. Down that road lies madness.

Comment: FTR, the `swrite()` function is described here: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform#Accessing-Formatting-Internals

Answer (score 5):

```
my @lines = (
  "It is true that printf and sprintf",
  "do not have a conversion to center-justify text.",
  "However, you can achieve the same effect",
  "by padding left-justified text",
  "with an appropriate number of spaces."
);

my $max_length = 0;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  $max_length = (length $line > $max_length) ? length $line : $max_length;
}

foreach my $line (@lines) {
  printf "%s%-${max_length}s\n", ' ' x int(($max_length - length $line)/2), $line;
}
```

Comment: All these people saying "This is impossible with printf..." Someone's gotta show them how to really program ;)

Comment: Sorry but this answer is broken. (As evident when you add some kind of trailing character to the output.)

Comment: @DevSolar The main difference between my answer and your modification is that you are effectively padding both the left and right sides of the input lines with spaces to output the same length for each line. I agree that would be a better technique if, for example, one wants to embed center-justified text between other text on a line. However, if the center-justified text is the only data to be printed on a line, then adding spaces to the end of each line is not necessary for display purposes (and increases the total data size for no benefit). Both techniques are valid for different use cases.

Comment: @Sam The right padding is only one part of it. Your solution also *always* adds padding to the left, using up extra screen space.  Nothing really serious (after all it's just prettifying output we are talking about), but it's not what I would think of when thinking "centrally justified".

Comment: @DevSolar actually my solution does NOT _always_ add padding on the left. If the line is the same as the max line length, then no padding is added. I've tested your lines and my lines thru both solutions and the left sides of the output lines are the same for both solutions. Anyway, I do want to thank you for pointing out another solution if and when padding is desired on the right side as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use two variables for each value you'd like to print and dynamically set the width of each around the value width.  The problem becomes a little trickier if you want consistent total widths when your value has an odd/even string length.  The following seems to do the trick!

```
use POSIX;
printf( "<%*s%*s>\n",
   ((10+length($_))/2), $_,
   ceil((10-length($_))/2), "" )
      for( qw( four five5 six666 7seven7 ) );
```

which prints

```
<   four   >
<  five5   >
<  six666  >
< 7seven7  >
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the `line width` for this. For example, printing centered lines to the terminal:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN {$cols=`tput cols`} print " " x (($cols-length)/2),$_;' /etc/passwd
```

Of course, this is *not* a `printf` formatting tag.

Comment: It would be better to delete or rewrite the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
my @lines = (
    "Some example lines",
    "of differing length",
    "to show a different approach",
    "that actually",
    "prints your content",
    "centered in its max-width block",
    "with minimal padding",
    "(which the answer",
    "by Sam Choukri does NOT do)."
);

# Get the required field width
my $max_length = 0;
foreach my $line ( @lines )
{
    $max_length = length( $line ) if ( length( $line ) > $max_length );
}

foreach my $line ( @lines )
{
    # First step, find out how much padding is required
    my $padding = $max_length - length( $line );

    # Get half that amount (rounded up) in spaces
    $padding = ( ' ' x ( ( $padding + $padding % 2 ) / 2 ) );

    # Print your output, with padding appended, right-justified to
    # a max-width field.
    # (Pipe character added to show that trailing padding is correct)
    printf "%${max_length}s|\n", $line . $padding;
}
```